# Port forward openvpn connection

Tags: port-forwarding, openvpn

Ok I've stuck on this for awhile and can't seem to get this figured out.  Currently I have a build server I would like to connect to a laptop with a beaglebone connected to it.  I would like my build server to be able to ssh to my beaglebone when I'm working remotely.  Currently I have an OpenVPN connection setup between my build server and laptop.  My laptop gets assigned the OpenVPN address of 10.8.0.6 and to show this is working I can connect from my build server to a local webserver on my laptop on port 80.  The final step I need is to connect from my build server to the beaglebone connected to the laptop at local address 192.168.7.2 port 22.  How do I forward the connection at 10.8.0.6:22 to 192.169.7.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure your laptop as a router with NAT. I assume that your laptop is running Linux.

1. Enable routing on your laptop:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

2. Configure firewall (iptables) to enable NAT and port forwarding:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.7.2:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 0/0 -s 192.168.7.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.7.0/24 -d 0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 0/0 -d 192.168.7.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

It should do the work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this and my build server times out when attempting to ssh in(ssh user@10.8.0.6).  Its tough since I'm not getting much feedback about whats wrong.

Comment: Check if your Beaglebone has default gateway set to address 192.168.7.1 (the IP address of your laptop in 192.168.7.x network). If not, then you have to add default gateway on beaglebone:
`route add default gw 192.168.7.1`

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much!! Seriously the IT guys at my work couldn't even get this working!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you can use netsh, like this:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5556 listenaddress=192.168.1.1 connectport=3389 connectaddress=192.168.1.10
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx